# How often is tag badge tracking updated?

Tags: support, bug, badges

I'm wondering whether I've misunderstood how tag badge tracking works. I've recently answered some Python questions, with up-votes, but that hasn't made its way into the 'Next tag badge' panel.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It looks like an inconsistency in how it's displayed, given that if I click on the cog icon, the dialog box shows the up-to-date count.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: Logged in on a different machine just now, still says 83.

Comment: A different machine you've used before, recently? Or one that has never seen SO?

Comment: For completeness, I just tried a Chrome incognito tab. Same thing.

Comment: Excellent :D Looks like a sync / updating issue indeed, then

Comment: The problem went away when I chose to track a different tag badge, and then went to Python again. Not sure if it will stay in sync once I answer more questions though.

Comment: Select another badge and reselect the badge you want to track. That'll update it instantly. I discovered it after I asked [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269961/tag-scores-displayed-on-the-tags-tab-and-the-tag-badge-tracker-do-not-match) question. It's also mentioned in [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267818/next-tag-badge-panel-score-and-answers-counter-discrepancy).

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, I wasn't able to find the right question earlier. Should I delete my question?

Comment: @Vlad No, don't delete it, just let it get closed as a dupe so it's easier for others to find in the future. If you had trouble finding that post, odds are good that others will as well.

Comment: For a while it was updating by itself every few days.  Then of late just on Sundays...except last night.